# question on Leibniz formula

Tags: calculus, integration, leibniz-integral-rule

let
$$f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}{\frac{\cos y\sin x}{y^2+y+1}dy}$$ then find all values of $x$ for which $f'(x)=0$?

I tried directly differentiating but I got stuck on $$f'(x)=\cos x\left(\int_1^x{\frac{\cos y}{y^2+y+1}dy}+\frac{\sin x}{x^2+x+1}\right)$$

Comment: The last integral is totally wrong

Comment: @MathAttack I did $f(x)=\sin x\int_1^x{\frac{cosy}{y^2+y+1}dy}$ then differentiated by product rule what did I do wrong?

Comment: @Gonçalo I edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given: $$f(x)=\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\cos y \sin x}{y^2+y+1} dy $$

Take the derivative (Using the product rule for the RHS): $$\implies \frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}[\sin(x)\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\cos y}{y^2+y+1} dy]$$
$$\implies f'(x)=\cos(x)\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\cos y}{y^2+y+1}dy +\frac{\cos x}{x^2+x+1}\sin x$$
Now we want to find all values of x such that $f'(x)=0$:
$$\cos x \int_{1}^{x}\frac{\cos y}{y^2+y+1} dy +\frac{\sin x \cos x}{x^2+x+1}=0$$
Well, notice that the integral will not be zero simultaneously with the other expression (As if $x=1$ (to make the integral zero), then the other expression is not zero; and if there exists an $x$ such that the integral is zero, the other expression won't be zero. Hence, it seems the only way to make this equation to be zero is to set $cos(x)=0$ and so $x=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ is the solution for all integers $n$.

Comment: Though, I am not sure 100% of my answer. So make sure either from the final solutions in the book or problem set you have, or if someone can confirm, please do so.

Comment: yeah your answer is right. the question was multiple choice so the question is kinda wrong question is actually asking for all x for which f'(x) is definitely 0 and not for all zeroes so sorry about that